# ModelState is false for relations with required fields

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two models Invoice and Client which has one to many relation. My problem is when I try to create a new invoice the modelstate becomes false because the required fields of the Client object are not filled. I tried to set default values e.g. `int property {get; set;} = 1;` but this causes to override the property value when I try to retrieve the relational model. I'm new to asp.net any help would be appreciated.

Here is my Client model code:

```
public class Client
{
    public int ClientId { get; set; }//Primary key

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Client/Company Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //.....


    public List<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }

}
```

Invoice Model:

```
public class Invoice
{
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }//Primary key

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Client/Company Name")]
    public int ClientId { get; set; }//Foreign key
    public Client client { get; set; }

    //....

}
```

My code to save an invoice:

```
[HttpPost]//Save quote & redirect to edit quote
    public IActionResult Create(Invoice quote)
    {
        ViewData["Title"] = "Create Quotation";//Set title of the view!

        if (ModelState.IsValid)//If quote is validated to true.
        {
            _context.Invoices.Add(quote);//insert quote
            _context.SaveChanges();

            //Redirect to edit page to add items to the invoice
            return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = quote.InvoiceId });
        }

        //...
    }
```

My code to retrieve invoices with their client names

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["Title"] = "Quotations";//Set title of the view!
        //Return with array of all quotations.
        return View(_context.Invoices.Include(i => i.client).Where(i => i.isQuote == true).ToArray());
    }
```

Any hints or help would be appreciated.

Comment: You get this issue because you're using entity models as viewmodels. Create a separate CreateInvoiceViewModel that only has a ClientID, and map it to the appropriate classes when persisting.

Comment: @CodeCaster is this the way to do it in asp.net, I mean is it a common practice?

Comment: Define "this"? Using viewmodels? Yes, that's a very common practice in MVC, in fact it is one of the cornerstones of that design pattern. Unfortunately, almost every ASP.NET MVC tutorial out there uses entity models as viewmodels, which is a bad practice for reasons you now encountered.

Comment: @CodeCaster, Cool, Thank you for your time to answer the question, yes I was following Microsoft's official documentation and scratching my head why is it not working. Can you post it as an answer so I can choose it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Sorry, got no time for writing a full-blown answer.

Comment: No Issues. I will put it by myself when I rewrite the viewmodel class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a simpler solution:

Just add `virtual` keyword and GG

in Invoice Model:

```
public class Invoice
{
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }//Primary key

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Client/Company Name")]
    public int ClientId { get; set; }//Foreign key
    public virtual Client client { get; set; }

    //....

}
```